# Angular 2 naviagate

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am learning Angular 2 and I have some trouble with navigate in my app. I have a login component and a app component. The app component is is the index file :

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

In my app.module I created routes :

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: AppComponent }
];
```

and in the imports of my ngModule I do that :

```js
RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
    )
```

But when I write "/login" in my address bar it redirect me in "/home" why ? How I do to display my login page ? I read a lot of tutorials on that but I understand nothing. Thank you

Edit : 
LoginComponent :

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AuthService } from './../auth.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent  {

  email: string;
  password: string;
  constructor(public authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {

  }
  signup() {
    this.authService.signup(this.email, this.password);
    this.email = this.password = '';
  }

  login() {
    this.authService.login(this.email, this.password).then(res => {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/kanban');
      console.log("works");
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log("not works");

    });
    this.email = this.password = '';
  }

  logout() {
    this.authService.logout();
  }

}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>Simply  Login</h2>
  <form fxLayout="column">
    <md-input-container>
      <input [(ngModel)]="email" name="email" required mdInput type="email" placeholder="Email">
    </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container>
      <input mdInput [(ngModel)]="password" name="password" required type="password" placeholder="Mot de passe">
    </md-input-container>

    <button (click)="login()" md-button type="submit">Se connecter</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: pls post code for `LoginComponent`

Comment: The app component is the root component, that is **always** displayed: it's your application. Inside the template of this component, you should have a router-outlet component, indicating where the component associated to that route goes. The component associated to the home route should NOT be the app component: you don't want th app component inside the app component. Read the official angular documentation.

Comment: @Dhyey I edit my post with the code thank you

Comment: @JBNizet So what I write in my app.component ? I read the official doc but I don't understand it,  English is not my native language.

Comment: As I just said, the app component template should (at least) have a router-outlet: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`.

Comment: @JBNizet Just that ? And in the .ts ?

Comment: In the class, you put the fields and methods needed by the template, as for any component. If the template doesn't need anything, you don't need anything.

Comment: Okay thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

In template of app.component put this

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

and in routing

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
];
```

The app Angular start in app.component is the root component

Comment: Thank you that's working. So what the purpose of the app.component ? How I use it ?

Comment: The app.component is the root component of app Angular, when you use routes you can not put app.component in the routing becouse the component needs a <router-outlet>, you can see app Angular how a tree of component where the app.component is the node first node